# Updating QTextDocument while user is typing

Tags: c++, qt

I'm pretty new to Qt and I'd like to do this thing that looks simple to me, though I don't really know where to start.

I use a QTextEdit whose style I'd like to update while the user is typing, for example, put everything between two stars in bold (I'm trying to make a basic Markdown editor).

Though, as I said, I don't know where to go. I wanted to use the `textChanged` signal, but if I do something like

```
on textChanged
    analyze the new text
    textEdit->setHtml(formatted new text)
```

The slot is just calling itself (and my app finally crashes) because my `onTextChanged` is changing the text...

What should I do ? I was thinking that I could work with threads (analyzing while the user is typing) but I fear that doing this might be difficult, since it would cause a non-UI thread to access and modify things in the UI one...

I'm really looking for design advice here...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the setHtml(QString) between two calls to [blockSignals(bool)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) to prevent the QTextEdit from emitting the textChanged() signal again.

```
textEdit->blockSignals(true);
textEdit->setHtml(text);
textEdit->blockSignals(false);
```

Don't know if it's the best design choice. You could try to study the QTextEdit API and see if it is worthing inheriting from it and specialize its behavior, even if I do not believed it was designed to be inherited.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll look into it. For now, I've found about [`QSyntaxHighliter`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) which seems to do what I wanted to achieve.